# Ryzen extremely slow on the most basic of tasks under Arch Linux

Tags: cpu, amd

I have a Ryzen 1700 which is extremely slow even in the most basic of tasks like launching vim or nvim (takes several seconds), tab switching in the Gnome Terminal or scrolling text.

The Ryzen 7 1700 is on a MSI Gaming Pro Carbing B350 mainboard with the newest BIOS and "amd-ucode" installed, 16 GB of DDR4 RAM at 2933 Mhz. GPU is an NVIDIA 1070 TI with the "nvidia" package installed. Kernel version is 5.9.13-arch1-1. IOMMU is disabled because it doesn't boot with it enabled.

### 7zip benchmark result

```
$ 7z b

7-Zip [64] 17.03 : Copyright (c) 1999-2020 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.03 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,16 CPUs x64)

x64
CPU Freq: 64000000 - - - - - - - -

RAM size:   16013 MB,  # CPU hardware threads:  16
RAM usage:   3530 MB,  # Benchmark threads:     16

                       Compressing  |                  Decompressing
Dict     Speed Usage    R/U Rating  |      Speed Usage    R/U Rating
         KiB/s     %   MIPS   MIPS  |      KiB/s     %   MIPS   MIPS

22:      34730  1351   2501  33786  |     467706  1567   2546  39891
23:      32301  1331   2472  32911  |     455850  1549   2546  39441
24:      31823  1385   2471  34217  |     435139  1506   2536  38194
25:      28978  1363   2427  33087  |     425605  1505   2517  37877
----------------------------------  | ------------------------------
Avr:            1358   2468  33500  |             1532   2536  38851
Tot:            1445   2502  36175
```

36175 MIPS seems to be [normal for the CPU](https://www.servethehome.com/amd-ryzen-7-1700-linux-benchmarks-zen-buy/amd-ryzen-7-1700-7-zip-compression-benchmark/) so maybe it is not clocking high enough on simple tasks?

### cpupower frequency-info

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.55 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.00 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 1.55 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.55 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "schedutil" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.55 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  3000MHz
    Pstate-P1:  2700MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1550MHz
```

### Update

I performed a full upgrade using `pacman -Syyu` on 2020-01-05 (last one was 2020-12-13), which upgraded, among others:

- amd-ucode (20201120.bc9cd0b-1 -> 20201218.646f159-1)
- linux (5.9.13.arch1-1 -> 5.10.4.arch2-1)
- linux-firmware (20201120.bc9cd0b-1 -> 20201218.646f159-1)

And it got much faster. I will keep my eyes open if that fixed it or if the problems will reoccurr.

Comment: What's the output of `cpupower frequency-info` (part of the cpupower package)?

Comment: I guess you are using GNOME. Are you on a wayland or on a X.org session? You can check that with `echo $XDG_DISPLAY_TYPE` or from login screen.

Comment: Also atm you could have to downgrade gnome-shell https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/68901.

Comment: @Wieland: I added the cpupower information.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck: I am using x11. I think I switched to it for the SimpleScreenRecorder that wouldn't work in Wayland.